# How do I loop through an array in LC-3 assembly and print out each item?

Tags: arrays, assembly, lc3

I have an array of size 10 that takes character input from a user. Now I just need to loop through the array and print out each character followed by a new line but I don't know where to start. LC-3 assembly is not my forte...
Here is my code so far:

```
LD R2, COUNTER
LEA R1, ARRAY
LD R4, COUNTER2

DO_WHILE_LOOP
    GETC
    STR R0, R1, #0
    ADD R1, R1, #1
    ADD R2, R2, #-1
    BRp DO_WHILE_LOOP
END_DO_WHILE_LOOP

LEA R3, ARRAY

OUT_LOOP

END_OUT_LOOP
HALT

;Local Data
ARRAY .BLKW #10
COUNTER .FILL #10
NEWLINE .STRINGZ "\n"
COUNTER2 .FILL #10
.END
```

My question is basically what do i put inside the OUT_LOOP?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a number of different ways to do this. When you're printing the characters back to the user do you have to do it after you've received all of the user's input?

You could just print back to the user while they are typing:

```
DO_WHILE_LOOP
    GETC
    OUT
    STR R0, R1, #0
    ADD R1, R1, #1
    ADD R2, R2, #-1
BRp DO_WHILE_LOOP
END_DO_WHILE_LOOP
```

If you have to print after collecting all of the user's input then you can just load the char array's memory location into R0 and then use the PUTs command.

Example:

```
LEA R0, ARRAY     ; Load the ARRAY memory location into R0
PUTs              ; Display all of the characters until it runs into null
```